# Can't open .mp4 with cv::VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to run the following simple code

```
# cat VideoCaptureTest.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string input("/root/OpenCVTest/720p.mp4");
  cv::VideoCapture capture(input);
  if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    cout << "Failed to open " << input << endl;
    exit (1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It gets compiled successfully with

```
# g++ -ggdb VideoCaptureTest.cpp -lopencv_videoio -o VideoCaptureTest
```

but `VideoCaptureTest` couldn't open the specified `.mp4` file though the file exists and could be inferred by `ffmpeg -i /root/OpenCVTest/720p.mp4`

```
# ./VideoCaptureTest
Failed to open /root/OpenCVTest/720p.mp4
```

I have compiled OpenCV with

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FILES=-wl,-Bsymbolic \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=1 \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_GENERATION=Turing \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_LAPACK=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF ..
```

could verify install using

```
# pkg-config --modversion opencv4
4.5.3
```

I'm running it on `nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04` docker container on an `Ubuntu 20.04 GCP VM` with a `T4` GPU. It doesn't have any graphical environment.

Comment: I've not built opencv from source, what is the result if you pass  `cv::CAP_FFMPEG` to the second argument  of  [`cv::VideoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ac4107fb146a762454a8a87715d9b7c96) ? did you try running `capture.open()` explicitly ?

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: running `capture.open(input)` gave the same result

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues/274 fixed the issue.
I need to

```
apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev  libswscale-dev libavresample-dev
```